# Модификация списка в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот хочу создать конвертер один, но возникли некоторые трудности. В общем можно ли как-то  сделать чтоб в моём списке выводились слова не в строчку, а в столбик + начинались из `0x` и в конце было `t`, ну без ковычек и символа `b`. Вот мой велосипед, с радостью выслушаю вашу критику)

```
import binascii
text_input = str.encode(input('Введите ваш текст: '))
a = binascii.hexlify(text_input)
lst = [a[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(a),2)]
print(lst)
```

Должно получатся что-то типа такого

```
0xd1t
0x82t
```

Comment: `for x in text_input: print(hex(x) + 't')`

Comment: Спасибо реально работает))